# When I deploy my xamarin forms app inside my project I see the map, but when I put it up on google play the map is not loading

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

Followed some guides but I cannot get it quite right. I will show you the process below that does not make it quite work.

First of all I started off by acquiring an API-key on google console and i put that into my project.

I acquired the sha 1 by typing this into the terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

The map now runs smoothly and fine in my xamarin project when I run it on my device.

Then when I try to upload the project I create a keystore named: "myproject.keystore" and I give it the Alias and password: "myproject" as well.

Just like this:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore myproject.keystore -alias myproject -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

When I now upload the app to google play and it gets accepted I cannot see the map.

Comment: Are you project settings different between DEBUG and RELEASE configurations? Also did you add the INTERNET permission?

Comment: Yes internet-permission is added. Debug and release should be the same? I have not changed anything so I assume they are the same?

Comment: If you run the app in RELEASE mode does the map show up normally?

Comment: the map does not show in REALEASE mode but in DEBUG mode i can see it just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try comparing your project settings between DEBUG and RELEASE to find a difference. Or check for any hard coded API keys or anything that that would be different between the two environments.

Edit:

So after your `myproject.keystore` is created, you need to extract the SHA-1 from that keystore and add that to the Credential list in Google.

So if you created your `myproject.keystore` in `~/Users/Someone/Desktop/`, then you would extract the keystore the same way you did with the DEBUG version:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/Users/Someone/Desktop/myproject.keystore
```

That should give you the second SHA-1 that you need to add to the Google site.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with how i take out the SHA-1? I acquire it by doing this now: `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`?

Comment: I am doing it but it says that it doesnt find it. I do it like this `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/Users/Johnny/Desktop/projectOne.keystore`. It says "Java.lang.exception" Keystore doesnt exist.. When I took out the SHA for debug then I just copied an alrdy existing line (the one that i mention first in the post).

Comment: @medvedo No problem. Glad it helped.